# Strange require path error

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm running into a very strange problem with my autoloader function.

This is my autoloader function, as taken from the [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md):

```
function __autoload($className) {

    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName = '';
    $namespace = '';
    $lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\');
    if ($lastNsPos) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
}
```

The only modifications I have made to the function are adding the `dirname(__FILE__)` to the `require` function as I'm keeping this function in a directory called `includes`, where all of my other classes are kept. This code has worked for another project of mine, so I'm not really sure what's going wrong here.

I have a file: `includes\SQL\Persistable.php` with the namespace declared as `namespace SQL;`. When the autoloader runs, it gives me this error:

```
Warning: require(/home/user/public_html/phpProject/includes/Persistable.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/phpProject/includes/config.php on line 52
```

I know that *that* file doesn't exist, but I'm not sure why it's loading that. It should be requiring `/home/user/public_html/phpProject/includes/SQL/Persistable.php`. However, when I change the `require` function like so (just to test):

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ' ' . $fileName;
```

I get:

```
Warning: require(/home/user/public_html/phpProject/includes/ SQL/Persistable.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/phpProject/includes/config.php on line 52
```

I'm not sure why adding a space, or in fact any character other than a forward-slash, will cause the `require` function to include the first part of the `$fileName`. I have also tried:

```
echo dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
```

And the output of that is:

```
/home/user/public_html/phpProject/includes/SQL/Persistable.php
```

However, it is clearly not interpreted like that in the `require` function. Why?

I've also tried `__DIR__`, explicitly setting the include path via `set_include_path()`, putting the function in its own separate file and including that, and `realname()`, none of them have worked. As I have said, **this code has worked before**, so I'm not sure why I'm coming up with this problem now!

Comment: Could you give us a stacktrace from xdebug, or something like that. Could that be that you're using class `Persistable`, without specifying namespace with `use SQL;`? In this case your autoloader will do exact what it does.

Comment: @devdRew I'm not sure how to install xdebug, but in my file the code that creates a `Persistable` instance is: `$section = new \SQL\Persistable();`. I didn't specify a `use` statement because I'm using an absolute path to the namespace\class here.

Comment: Try to put 'var_dump($className)' at the beginning of the __autoload() function and complete your question with output you got. Cause it seems to me most likely that somewhere in your project you're using not absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending statement was the fetching of the results of a prepared statement:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Persistable');
```

Changing it to:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS | \PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, '\SQL\Persistable');
```

Helped resolve the problem...but now I'm facing a problem with PDO, which is in another question.